Derive elasticities from partial dependences
I am producing a partial dependences plot based on a random forests (RF) binary classification model, which yields predicted probabilty of observation $i$ belong to class A for the outcome variable Z. The partial dependence plot in question provides, in my understanding, the probability (shown by the color) of class A of variable Z to occur conditional to the value of two features (X and Y variables), while assuming all the other features to remain constant:

My question is whether I can derive the local partial elasticities (% change in the probability of Z to be of class A to a 1% change in $X$ based on the lattice shown in the figure as:
$\epsilon^{X}_{ij} = \frac{\frac{PD_{i,j}}{PD{i-1, j}} - 1}{\frac{X_{i}}{X{i-1}} - 1} $
where $PD$ is the partial dependence value of Z at $i,j$ coordinates of X and Y.
Or there some mathematical reason why this reasoning does not work?
